# Solving a matrix equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Questions in this general form have been asked a lot here, but I've searched for hours and I haven't found any that I can generalize to my problem, so I've asked it again:

I've been given three matrices,
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
     5 & 3 \\
     3 & 2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$, 
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
     6 & 2 \\
     2 & 4 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$, and have to solve the equation AX+B = X. I've no clue where to start at all, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Copy-paste error, fixed.

Comment: What about re-arranging, $AX-X=-B$ then $(A-I)X=-B$ so $X=-(A-I)^{-1}B$.  This of course assumes that you can find the inverse of $A-I$.

Comment: what about solving $(I-A)X = B?$

Comment: Can you explain how you moved from AX−X=−B to (A−I)X=−B?

Comment: @user $M = IM=MI$ for every matrix $M$ and appropriately shaped $I$., So you have $AX - X = AX - IX = (A-I)X$ since distribution holds in matrix arithmetic as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AX+B-X=0$

$(A-I)X=-B$

$X=-(A-I)^{-1}B$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

And, here's an example to model this process:

[image]

Comment: why is the font so huge?